# Passando variáveis de AJAX para ASP

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp

Tenho um FORM de contato que usa uma função em AJAX para validar e devolver um PARÂMETRO de sucesso que me permite enviar a mensagem SEM o visitante sair da página de contato.

Normalmente, uso estes FORMs em páginas HTML e a função PROCESSA e ENVIA a mensagem no backend, sem intervenção nenhuma.

Funciona! mas só se o servidor rodar PHP.

Num servidor WINDOWS não funciona. Isto porque dentro do AJAX vou precisar carregar a página que trata e envia as variáveis no formato de e-mail. Num servidor WINDOWS precisarei de uma página em ASP clássico.

A função no HTML funciona, no ASP funciona, mas não consigo fazer o ajax enviar para a página ASP, as variáveis vindas do FORM, para que o ASP capture e trate a mensagem.

Vou colar aqui o trecho em questão:

```js
var dataString = '?name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message + '&fone=' + fone;
// alert (dataString);return false;

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"contact.asp",
            data:dataString,
            success:function () {
                $('#af-form').prepend("<strong>Sua mensagem foi enviada!</strong> Em breve entraremos em contato.<br>&nbsp;");
                $('#af-form')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
```

Se eu criar uma página PHP com as mesmas instruções da página ASP, o AJAX envia os dados corretamente (mas obviamente não processa).

Então o que preciso é ALTERAR a maneira como o conteúdo de datastring está sendo passado. E aí, amigos, só pedindo ajuda aos universitários.

*** ATENÇÃO ***
1) Leia a questão com atenção;
2) Abstenha-se de respostas do tipo "Tá, mas porque ASP?"
3) Sugira caminhos alternativos, mas procure manter a integridade da função.
4) Seja gentil e educado com quem sabe menos que você.

[]'s

Comment: Hélio, veja se esse link te ajuda: https://goo.gl/1ao3BR .

Comment: É uma abordagem interessante (obrigado!), mas ela parte do pressuposto que meu documento de origem é um ASPX. Na verdade o que tenho em mãos é um HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seu ajax assim.

```
let name;
let email:
name = document.getElementById('name');
email= document.getElementById('email');

//voê pode setar o email ao inves do getElementById com o $ com jquery
//exemplo:
name = $('#name').val();
email = $('#email').val();

// alert (dataString);return false;

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"contact.asp",
            data : { name : name, email : email },
            // se não funcionar utilizar com o encodeURIComponent
            // data : { name : encodeURIComponent(name), email : encodeURIComponent(email)},
            success:function () {
                $('#af-form').prepend("<strong>Sua mensagem foi enviada!</strong> Em breve entraremos em contato.<br>&nbsp;");
                $('#af-form')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
```

ou ainda

```
name = document.getElementById('name');
email= document.getElementById('email');

$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"contact.asp?name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email),
            success:function () {
                $('#af-form').prepend("<strong>Sua mensagem foi enviada!</strong> Em breve entraremos em contato.<br>&nbsp;");
                $('#af-form')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
```

o input deve conter o id

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
```

Para resgatar os dados no Asp você deve fazer assim para method GET

```
dim name
name = Request.QueryString("name")
```

Para resgatar os dados no Asp você deve fazer assim para method POST

```
dim name
name = Request.Form("name")
```

Se me lembro bem esse abaixo deve funcionar nos 2

```
dim name
name = Request("name")
```

Aconselho a sempre remover as aspas simples antes de inserir isso no banco de dados se for o caso para não haver sql injection

```
dim name
name = Request.QueryString("name").Replace("'","")
```

Não tive chance de testar o código mas deve funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito, bro. Há apenas um detalhezinho a ajustar relativo à codificação. mas a função cumpre o que se espera! Obrigado, valeu!!